# How to query a collection through multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to collect objects that are all connected through multiple layers of associations, and I don't know who to do so.

I need to get a collection of CustomText based on a string query param.

Basically I need to do a query that will pull a collection of CustomText by name:

```
@searched_content = params[:search].downcase
@query = CustomText.where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{@searched_content}%")
```

but then also filters the `@query` to only search LineItems that have been a part of an approved order.  I am using Spree, where `Spree::Order` `has_many` `Spree::LineItem`.  Basically, doing something like this (doesn't work at all, but hopefully you'll be able to see what I'm trying to do):

```
@query = Spree::LineItem.joins(:order).where(spree_orders: {state: "complete"}).joins(:custom_texts).where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{@searched_content}%"))
```

Models:

```
class CustomText < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :custom_set, :inverse_of => :custom_texts
end

class CustomSet < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :spree_line_item, :class_name => Spree::LineItem, :foreign_key => :spree_line_item_id
   has_may :custom_texts, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :custom_set
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :custom_texts, :through => :custom_sets
   has_many :custom_sets, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => :spree_line_item_id
end
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get when running the query you say doesn't work at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was just a simple syntax error with one too many end parenthesis at the end...stupid spelling error.

```
@query = Spree::LineItem.joins(:order).where(spree_orders: {state: "complete"}).joins(:custom_texts).where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{@searched_content}%")
```